# Annotation in a pgfplots document

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, annotations

What have I to modify in this code to get simple annotations ?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xtick={45,46,...,55},
ytick={0,0.1,...,1},
width=18cm,
height=10cm,
grid=major,
minor x tick num=9,
%minor y tick num={1},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
xmin=45,
xmax=55,
]
\addplot[mark=none, blue, line width=1.5pt] coordinates {(45,0)(47,0.1)(49,0.35)(51,0.775)(53,0.875)(55,1)};

\addplot[mark=none, dashed, red] coordinates {(0,0.5)(49.7,0.5)(49.7,0.5)(49.7,0)};
\node at (axis cs:49.7,-0.15){Me};

\addplot[mark=none, dashed, red] coordinates {(0,0.25)(48.2,0.25)(48.2,0.25)(48.2,0)};
\node at (axis cs:48.2,-0.15){$Q_1$};

\addplot[mark=none, dashed, red] coordinates {(0,0.75)(50.9,0.75)(50.9,0.75)(50.9,0)};
\node at (axis cs:50.9,-0.15){$Q_3$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You are drawing the annotations *outside* the `axis` environment, so they are clipped. Add `clip=false` to the `axis` options and they will appear. (But then also your dashed lines will not be clipped any more, so you should adjust them, too.)

Comment: @StefanPinnow `clip mode=individual`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. of course, I always miss this ... (But that is most probably, because I have never used it before -- I think ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Torbjørn already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338976/annotation-in-a-pgfplots-document#comment831494_338976) a "quick fix" to your problem would be to simply use `clip mode=individual`, but "your" way is -- in my opinion -- not the ideal solution to add annotations.

Here I present another method using `extra ticks`. For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use `compat' level 1.11 or higher so you don't need to add
        % `axis cs:' to each TikZ coordinate
        compat=1.11,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
%            % not needed, because this is the default with this scales
%            xtick={45,46,...,55},
            % and instead of applying the `ytick`s just give the "distance"
            ytick distance=0.1,
            %
            width=18cm,
            height=10cm,
            grid=major,
            minor x tick num=9,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            xmin=45,
            xmax=55,
            %
            % if you don't want to draw markers (anywhere), disable it globally
            no markers,
            % where do you want to draw the extra labels ...
            extra x ticks={48.2,49.7,50.9},
            extra x tick style={
                % and what should the labels state
                xticklabels={$Q_1$,Me,$Q_3$},
                % adjust the style so it fits your needs ...
                % you don't want to draw (extra) grid lines there
                grid=none,
                % you also don't want to draw extra ticks there
                major tick length=0pt,
                % and the labels should be moved below the "normal" ticklabels
                xticklabel style={
                    yshift=-3ex,
                },
                % to align the labels on the same baseline
                % (for your current labels that doesn't change anything,
                %  but if you change e.g. "Me" to "me" and "$Q_3$" to
                %  "${Q_3^2}^2$", you will see the difference, if you comment
                %  the next line)
                typeset ticklabels with strut,
            },
        ]
        \addplot[mark=none, blue, line width=1.5pt] coordinates {
            (45,0)(47,0.1)(49,0.35)(51,0.775)(53,0.875)(55,1)
        };

        % you only need _3_ coordinates to plot the dashed lines
        % and so you don't need to adapt the "lower" values when changing the
        % axis limits, just use them directly in the coordinates
        \addplot [dashed, red] coordinates {
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0.25)
            (48.2,0.25)
            (48.2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
        };
        % but you can also do it with _2_ coordinates using TikZ's `\draw' command
        \draw [dashed, red]
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0.5) -| (49.7,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
        ;
        \draw [dashed, red]
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0.75) -| (50.9,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
        ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: It seems `ytick distance` and  `typeset ticklabels with strut` don't work (I've tried it with TeXmaker and Texwriter which is written for Android).

Comment: By commenting it, your method is right

Comment: What do you mean with "don't work"? Do you get an error message or does your output look other than mine when using above code? At least `ytick distance` was introduced in PGFPlots v1.13, so you would get an error message when you have an older version.

Comment: Right. .I get an error message

Comment: As already stated, most probably then you have an older PGFPlots version than v1.13. So after updating the issue should be solved.

Comment: I get the following error message : I do not know the key \tikz \ytick. ...etc..and the same kind of message about typeset ticklabels with strut.

Comment: sorry, but I think I cannot help you with this little information. Both keys are PGFPlots keys so they should be `/pgfplots/ytick` and `/pgfplots/typeset ticklabels with strut`. So when you use them in the `axis` options there should be no problem (when you have the most recent PGFPlots version (v1.14)) and don't have somewhere above these keys something like `/tikz/.cd`. If you still have this problem, please ask a new question, reduce the above code to the absolute minimum where the error message still appears and also include the relevant error message part from the log.